# How to obtain value_count() of different data types of elements in a series with "Object" data type?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pandas assign dtype "object" to a series that contains mixture of numeric and non numeric data. Is it possible to obtain a value count of dtypes of all the elements in a series?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AMC: No need for a negative comment/vote when there is already an accepted answer.

Comment: That would kind of defeat the point of this site, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can

```
pd.Series([1,'1']).map(type).value_counts()
Out[65]: 
<class 'int'>    1
<class 'str'>    1
```

Comment: pd.Series([1,'1']).apply(type).value_counts()